# How Much Longer For The Gene For Blue Eyes?

Tags: genetics, eyes

In the year 1900 roughly 50% of the people in the United States were homozygous for the gene for blue eyes. By 1950 the number had dropped down to 30%. Just now, (2013) barely 12% of the people living in America are homozygous for the blue eye gene.

Given the current rates of third world immigration into the United States. When will the last blue eyed man and the last blue eyed woman conceive a child with blue eyes? Should people with blue eyes bring reverse discrimination suits?

Reference:http://www.boston.com/news/globe/living/articles/2006/10/17/dont_it_make_my_blue_eyes_brown/ By Douglas Belkin

Comment: Do you have any reference for this 50% value? I highly doubt it, since blue is a recessive allel.

Comment: Agree with @Chris,you should give a reference for every data that you have put !

Comment: @user10739 could you paste the quote - the link is behind a paywall

Comment: If you come through the first link via Google, you can read it: https://www.google.de/#q=%22Don%27t+it+make+my+blue+eyes+brown%22+boston+globe

Comment: You added something to the question about reverse discrimination suits, but I don't see any other reference to discrimination. What is the alleged discrimination being inflicted upon blue-eyed people?

Comment: The 'alleged discrimination being inflicted upon blue-eyed people' is a collection of social policies in the United States leading to their extermination.

Answer (score 7):

Never.

Even if the country arrives at the unlikely day when there is no one alive in the United States with the blue eye phenotype, there are still plenty of people with the unexpressed recessive gene, and if two of them get together, those genes can combine to produce another blue-eyed child. If this happens twice, with one boy and one girl, and they happen to meet when they are in college and say "Hey cool, you have the same inexplicably rare kind of eyes as me. I think I want to marry you." then any children they have will also be blue eyed.

So even if the day came when you couldn't find a soul in the world with blue eyes, you will still never know if you've seen the end of them.